# SQL Server 2016 GROUP BY + HAVING only get different records by JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count, sql-server-2016

We have two tables, one for users and one for records. Records have a reference number and link to a user by a FK. We want to get reference numbers from the records table where the same reference number was used for different users. Two users are the same user if they have the same last name and same date of birth. Two users are different users if either last name or DOB are different.

Sample data:

```
DECLARE @user TABLE (id INT, fname VARCHAR, lname VARCHAR, dob VARCHAR(3))
DECLARE @record TABLE (id INT, refno VARCHAR, fk INT)

--first two are the same people because same firstname + lastname + date of birth
INSERT INTO @user SELECT 1, 'a', 'a', 'jan' 
INSERT INTO @user SELECT 2, 'a', 'a', 'jan'
--next two are the same people because same firstname + lastname + date of birth
INSERT INTO @user SELECT 3, 'b', 'b', 'feb'
INSERT INTO @user SELECT 4, 'b', 'b', 'feb'
--next two are different people because same firstname + lastname but different date of birth
INSERT INTO @user SELECT 5, 'c', 'c', 'mar'
INSERT INTO @user SELECT 6, 'c', 'c', 'apr'
--next two are different people because same firstname + date of birth but but different surname
INSERT INTO @user SELECT 7, 'd', 'e', 'may'
INSERT INTO @user SELECT 8, 'd', 'f', 'may'
--next two are different people because same firstname + date of birth but but different surname
INSERT INTO @user SELECT 9, 'd', 'e', 'may'
INSERT INTO @user SELECT 10, 'd', 'f', 'may'

--with simplified ref nos
INSERT INTO @record SELECT 10, '1', 1
INSERT INTO @record SELECT 11, '1', 2
INSERT INTO @record SELECT 12, '2', 3
INSERT INTO @record SELECT 13, '2', 4
INSERT INTO @record SELECT 14, '3', 5
INSERT INTO @record SELECT 15, '3', 6
INSERT INTO @record SELECT 16, '3', 7
INSERT INTO @record SELECT 17, '3', 8
INSERT INTO @record SELECT 18, 'a', 9
INSERT INTO @record SELECT 19, 'a', 10
```

What I've tried:

```
SELECT r.refno
, count(1) cnt
FROM @record r
INNER JOIN @user u ON u.id = r.fk
GROUP BY u.lname
    , r.refno
    , u.dob
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

Which returns:

```
refno   cnt
1       2
2       2
```

but the expected output is:

```
refno     cnt
3         4
a         2
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just fix your `SQL` Query with below :

```
SELECT A.refno,
       SUM(cnt) cnt
FROM
(
    SELECT r.refno,
           COUNT(*) cnt
    FROM @record r
         INNER JOIN @user u ON u.id = r.fk
    GROUP BY u.lname,
             r.refno,
             u.dob
) A
WHERE A.cnt = 1
GROUP BY A.refno;
```

Result :

```
refno     cnt
3         4
a         2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
SELECT refno
    , COUNT(1) AS cnt
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT u.lname
        , r.refno
        , u.dob
    FROM @record r
    INNER JOIN @user u ON u.id = r.fk
) AS t
GROUP BY refno
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1;
```